# Python UDP Server Issue

Tags: python, udp

On my Python UDP server I am coding, every time the same client sends a login packet to the server it duplicates the response on the server. For example one time it does print("example") then next time does that again but multiple times doing so again and again until it gets massive. I have pretty much tried nothing so far as I have been overly confused and have found nothing that might help me except it maybe has something to do with UDP Reflection.

NOTE: I plan to add encryption in the future!

```
import socket
import threading
import queue

messages = queue.Queue()
clients = []

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind(("localhost", 9898))
except:
    print("Failed to create the socket!")

def receiveHandler():
    while True:
        try:
            message, addr = s.recvfrom(988)
            messages.put((message, addr))
        except:
            pass

def loginHandler():
    while True:
        while not messages.empty():
            message, addr = messages.get()
            if addr not in clients:
                clients.append(addr)
            for client in clients:
                try:
                    if message.decode().startswith("L"):
                        packetSplit = message.decode().split(":")

                        username = packetSplit[1]
                        password = packetSplit[2]

                        if username == "Obsolete" and password == "Tester":
                            print("Username and Password correct!")
                        else:
                            print("Username or Password is incorrect!")

                        print(username)
                        print(password)
                except:
                    clients.remove(client)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=receiveHandler)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=loginHandler)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: I hope this is a school project, toy example, or prototype before you add encryption to the connection and an actual authentication system

Comment: I am going to add that in the future.